# How do I change the axis on a single panel in a lattice plot

Tags: r, lattice, axis-labels

I have been trying for awhile now to solve a problem with lattice plots. I have an uneven number of panels and so if I impose non-alternating axis labels one of the panels doesn't have an X axis label.

The following code is not for my specific project but uses an R dataset that is available to all:

```
densityplot(~Taste|Wine,data=WineTasting, as.table=TRUE, 
        scales=list(alternating=FALSE), 
        panel=function(x,y,...){ 
           panel.densityplot(x,plot.points=FALSE) 
           } 
)
```

And this produces a plot that looks like the first image:
 [Image 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OQZLO.png)

See how "Wine B" has no X axis. I want all the panels to have axis tick marks and numeric labels on the bottom. So if I insert panel.axis(side="bottom") I get an error message and a plot that looks like like the second image: 
[Image 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/76nVB.png)

I also tried the following code:

```
densityplot(~Taste|Wine,data=WineTasting, as.table=TRUE, 
        scales=list(alternating=FALSE), 
        panel=function(x,y,...){ 
          panel.densityplot(x,plot.points=FALSE) 
            }, 
        if(isTRUE(panel.number(2))){ 
          panel.axis(side="bottom") 
        } 
)
```

But this just produces an error message that reads:

"Error in get("lattice.status", envir = .LatticeEnv)[[prefix]][[name]] : 
  subscript out of bounds"

Can anyone help me get an axis on the bottom of that single panel (Wine B)?

Thanks, 
Matt

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have to get a little creative with clipping.

```
library(lattice)

densityplot(~ mpg | cyl, data = mtcars, as.table = TRUE, 
    scales = list(alternating = FALSE),
    par.settings = list(clip = list(panel = "off")),
    panel = function(x, y, ...) { 
       panel.densityplot(x, plot.points = FALSE, ...)
       if (panel.number() == 2) {
         panel.axis(side = "bottom", outside = TRUE)
       }
    }
)
```

[image: Imgur]

Comment: @MatthewSnyder -- I'm glad it worked out for you. Please consider accepting it as the answer if you think it solved your problem.